# How to make reponsive background and only horizontal scrolling

Tags: css, background, scroll

Hello and thanks in advance for the help :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
#bg {
    position:fixed; 
    top:-50%; 
    left:-50%; 
    width:200%; 
    height:200%;
}
#bg img {
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    right:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    margin:auto; 
    min-width:50%;
    min-height:50%;
}       
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bg">
        <img src="images/bck.png" >
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

I need some help to get it similar to the background that you find on this website: http://hotdot.pro/en/

As you can see I managed to make it resize accordingly but i don't get the best results with the horizontal scroll bar(for now it is ok if the bar is displayed).

The idea is that the width is 3 times larger than the height and I was thinking to achieve this with `overflow-x: auto` and `overflow-y:hidden` as shown in the example from the second row, 6-th column on these website: http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html

So thank you in advance and feel free to make changes to the code because I really understand better by example.

Comment: `overflow: auto;` will only add scroll bars along the axes that need them. Even `overflow: scroll;` won't force your site to be able to scroll past its full width; it will just place a greyed-out scroll bar when the site is at or above full width/height.

Comment: [Here's a great tutorial for it](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique--net-27641). The technique is called horizontal parallax scrolling, in your case it is also full page. [Here are some more examples of the technique](http://onepagelove.com/tag/horizontal-parallax-scrolling)

Comment: it is not about creating the parallax site but the image that is resizing in combination with horizontal scrolling